# CLOS: Format initialization argument list for make-instance

Tags: formatting, common-lisp, clos

I've been scratching my head on this for a while now - maybe someone could shed some light on how to format an initialization argument list for 'make-instance' from a nested list containing (key value) sublists. Example:

```
(make-instance 'myclass :initarg1 1 :initarg2 2 :initarg3 '(a b))
```

If I have the keywords and values in a list like so:

```
'((initarg1 1) (initarg2 2) (initarg3 '(a b)))
```

Any help and pointers appreciated!

Thanks,
Marleynoe

Answer (score 1):

```
(apply #'make-instance 'myclass
       (loop for (parameter value) in '((initarg1 1) (initarg2 2) (initarg3 '(a b)))
             collect (intern (symbol-name parameter) (find-package :keyword))
             collect value))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(apply #'make-instance 'myclass
       (mapcan #'(lambda (param)
                   (list (intern (symbol-name (car param)) (find-package :keyword))
                         (cadr param)))
               '((initarg1 1) (initarg2 2) (initarg3 '(a b)))))
```

The idea is that each `(initargk k)` parameter pair is mapped to a fresh list `(:initargk k)` and then all of them are concatenated in order together. This is a typical pattern for the map function `mapcan`.

Comment: A high quality answer should contain some explanation in text, not just code.